# how to recover all erased data from my Hard disk

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

i was using Windows 10. I had 3 partitions before.Then one of my friend tried to do dual boot in my system with ubuntu14.During this process instead of dual booting he Accidentally deleted my windows 10 and all my data from my Hard Disk.(It was so important and sentimental data that was deleted)Now the machine is running with Ubuntu OS.i have tried recovering with terminal with this command.

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk(installed testdisk)
sudo photorec(run photorec)
```

Then asked for select partition

```
Disk/dev/sda-500GB/465 GiB(RO)-THOSHIBA MQ01ABF050
              Start   End          size in sector
                0     976773167     97673168(whole disk)
```

And start The recovery But the recovering files look like this
 f000920.dll,f000120.txt,f000511.exe,f000024.java etc(more than around 500 of them in a folder) In folder named Recup_dir.1,Recup_dir.2,Recup_dir.3 etc(not completed yet still running) so its impossible to organize like it were before (and my Java projects and some of my own Java codes are arranged in a folder before Now it is shattered across the folders with unrecognizable names.So there is no way i can read all the files(From 970,000000) and find which is which in this lifetime. So is there any other way i can use to get all my data by folder by folder or at least with same file name.I'm ready for any other alternatives please help Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on what you described you have made data recovery nearly impossible bacause of the actions you have taken

Answer (score 0):

Recovery or do a restore of your system from the latest backup of the backup you took before you make the change.

Comment: All files of any importance should have at least one backup copy while those of particular importance should have 2 or more backup copies, preferably stored in different locations. Data recovery methods cannot be relied on. Sorry, can't help with recovery.

Comment: "Any data not stored in at least three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary."

Comment: helpful comments are appreciated

Answer (score -1):

bro kindly download DEFT linux, stands for "Digital Evidence and Forensic Toolkit" it is basically designed to recover data from hardisks, it contains builtin tools that can help you in recovering your lost data.
Regards!

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: You can't recover it if it's been written over already.